# Folder contents on target server are deleted on publish

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have an app where images can be uploaded. The images are uploaded to wwwroot/images. The wwwroot does not contain anything else.

When using app publish in Visual Studio 2017 the contents of the target server folder will be deleted as the images are not in the development environment.

I tried adding the following in the .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\images\" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and in .pubxml:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  wwwroot\images
</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

With all options enabled, the contents of the target server is still adjusted to the contents of the development server.

How do I disable server deletion for this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that option **Remove additional files at destination** is disabled in publish settings.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but i want to delete all contents on the target server, except this one folder. Is this possible?